# Using jquery, show a modal window only if the user is not registered

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is for show the modal window:

```
$('.overlay').show();
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".overlay").fadeOut();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I want to show the modal window only If the user is not registred in the database.

Comment: nothing is registered with jquery here. you are just checking display property of overlay class. if you want conditional jquery binding you need to add this script in php condition so that it will include in html render only when user is registered

Comment: you'll have to write up PHP code to connect with the database and check if the user exists, show us what you have tried so far, or you can find many really good examples online on how to connect to the Database with PHP.

Comment: This question seems likely to be closed, might I suggest reading the "[ask]" guidelines so that, in future, you might ask a question with which we're able to help?

Comment: Sorry is my first question here.

Comment: I have a modal window for register and i want hide this modal if the user registers

Answer (score 0):

add php condition to the script itself. or chnage the display property in the html by php variable itself.

```
<?php if($userid){ ?>
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".overlay").fadeOut();
}, 5000);
</script>
<?php } ?>
```